# Debian packaging with pyinstaller one dir

Tags: pyinstaller, debian-packaging

I have a python application that I need to distribute across multiple raspberries, currently using a debian package.

Currently I'm packaging a single executable file using pyinstaller, however in my latest development I'm using tensorflow, which results in a large binary file (>400MB).
Besides taking more than 5 minutes to load the application, the file system is getting full of the `_MEI***` folders that are created, occupying more than 1GB ([How the One-File Program Works](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-file-program-works))

To address this, I tried to generate the application with the `onedir` approach instead of the `onefile`.
Unfortunately I'm now struggling to find out where to install the different files that are generated in the `dist` folder (`/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib/`, `/usr/local/lib`?)

NOTE: Right now installing the .deb, places the files in `/usr/lib/` and creates a symbolic link for the executable inside the `/usr/bin/`. This is not working, and structurally, doesn't seems ok to me.

Does this makes sense at all, do you see any other approach to solve the problem?

Comment: does this [gist](https://gist.github.com/igricart/b930e60457f0eaa139d7dbee3c640ec7) help?

Comment: I tried using dh-python as you told, and since it is now using the setuptools, the source code is being installed in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages. What happens if i install two debians that have the same source folder structure? One replaces the other?